# developing a picker that pops out from the selected frame downward in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup

I have a design i'm trying to implement. Although I've ben working with Rg.plugin for a while trying out different animations and entry behaviour but it's always covering the whole screen.

However, the current design I'm working with is different.

here is the image
[image]

Please does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this using xamarin forms please.
Any help will be appreciated.

Note, I already have the design in place using pancakeView and Rg.plugin to pop it out on click. However, the positioning is what I haven't been able to achieve. though I've not written any code for it yet cos I prefer to do my research right.

Please I need anyone to point me to the right path or how to achieve this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Using a drop down like that is not really something well suited for phone idioms. I would recommend using the platform specific pickers instead for stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot, you can do custom control using entry and ListView to get it, there is also one custom control that you can take a look:

Installing **Xamarin.Forms.EntryAutoComplete**

Uisng this custom control like:

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="demo3.listviewsample.Page36"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:customControl="clr-namespace:EntryAutoComplete;assembly=EntryAutoComplete">
<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout>
        <customControl:EntryAutoComplete
            ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}"
            MaximumVisibleElements="5"
            Placeholder="Enter country..."
            SearchMode="{Binding SearchMode}"
            SearchText="{Binding SearchCountry}"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
 public class dialogvidemodel:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _searchCountry = string.Empty;
   
    private SearchMode _searchMode = SearchMode.Contains;

    public string SearchCountry
    {
        get => _searchCountry;
        set
        {
            _searchCountry = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SearchCountry");
        }
    }

    public List<string> Countries { get; } = new List<string>
    {
        "African Union",
        "Andorra",
        "Armenia",
        "Austria",
       
        "Togo",
        "Turkey",
        "Ukraine",
        "USA",
        "Wales"
    };

    public SearchMode SearchMode
    {
        get => _searchMode;
        set
        {
            _searchMode = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SearchMode");
        }
    }
}
```

More detailed info, please take a look:

https://github.com/krzysztofstepnikowski/Xamarin.Forms.EntryAutoComplete

Comment: Thanks for this piece. I'll try it out and see if it gives the desirable result

Comment: @DevLayi If my reply help you, please remember to mark reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: The autocomplete didn't solve my issue. so I resulted to using a custom popup with a listview and itemtapped event then use MessageCenter to pass the string to view. note, I made the string recipient observable

Comment: @DevLayi Glad to hear that you solved your problem.